# Troubles trying to tag Amazon FSx through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

So I'm trying to tag our first FileSystem in Amazon FSx.

However, this can only be done through AmazonCLI Access in which I'm using. 
However, I seem to hit the same issue everytime I try to tag this.

I have tried a few queries in the CLI and below is the output im receiving.

> PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> aws fsx
>   tag-resource --resource-arn
>   arn:aws:fsx:eu-central-1:********:key/********* --tags
>   "Key=Application Value=Nexus" --profile *******
>
> An error occurred (BadRequest) when calling the TagResource operation:
>   Null value provided as input PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS
>   Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> aws fsx tag-resource --resource-arn
>   arn:aws:fsx:eu-central-1:********:key/******* --tags "Key=Application
>   Value=Nexus" --profile *********
>
> An error occurred (BadRequest) when calling the TagResource operation:
>   Null value provided as input PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS
>   Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> aws fsx tag-resource --resource-arn
>   fs-********* Key=Application Value=Nexus" --profile *********
>
> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the TagResource
>   operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::*******:assumed-role/**-********/******@*****.com is not
>   authorized to perform: fsx:TagResource on resource: fs-***********

I expected this to take the key:value and tag this howeveer Im receving a lot of error messages.

I have Amazon FSX Full-admin IAM Policy! So this TagResource Operation should not be happening. I have also stimulated the policy and it says it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this now

This was due to the format of the ARN:

here is the --resource-arn format that needs to be used.

````
arn:aws:fsx:region:accountnumber:file-system/fs-********```
````